# Same origin policy on mobile apps

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, cross-domain

I've been researching this issue and I can't find an answer that satisfies me.

I'm very aware of the same origin policies as they apply to websites in a standard web browser. My question came up when I started developing a mobile app that uses the native webview and loading in site content with jQuery's `.load` method. Typically in a standard web browser I would get an XHR load error.

So, what are the rules regarding native apps and cross origin policies?

Comment: As far as I know, the device acts as a server, and can access content from 'any' URL. If you're using phonegap, you will have to add your domains to it's whitelist (or a wildcard)

Comment: I have the access origins set up in xcode and eclipse so I know that is needed to access those sites in the webview. Do you have any documentation on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robot Woods is definitely on the right track. When dealing with a native application, you are in a sense making requests from file://, instead of from https://. Because you are not making a request across the HTTP protocol, the same rules do not apply. When making requests from your native mobile app, you should be to make requests to any domain without any problems.

You only need to add the domain to the whitelist in PhoneGap/Cordova if you will be having that entire page replace your normal content in the webview, which normally doesn't happen (you normally are just requesting data in chunks from your server, instead of doing a window.location change).

Comment: You are right, but what if the service is controlling origin and does not allow file:// schema? Isn't there a way to remove the origin from request?

Comment: @MichaelBurger you might want to open a new question on that one. Sounds like there are more details behind what you're asking that would help folks give you a better answer than in comments.

Comment: I did it already, perhaps can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758914/cordova-or-phonegap-http-requests-and-same-origin-policy-problems

Comment: Gave it a go, though I'm not 100% clear on the issue.